# jQuery cssText not working with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple minimal example of html code containing two boxes:

```
<div class="box current" style="background: red"></div>
<div class="box" style="background: blue"></div>
```

And a css for it which makes the boxes invisible on default:

```
.box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

And and, a simple jquery code which is supposed to make the div with a class "current" visible by a certain variable ammount

```
var opacity = 0.7;
//Yes, the code has to use a variable. 
//NOT a static value;
$(".current").css("cssText", "opacity: " + opacity + " !important;");
```

Yet, for an unknown reason this code does not seem to work at all. 
Setting the css for the current box as static important makes it work nice...for a static value of the opacity.
**[CODEPEN LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Goejyo)**

Any help on the topic would be amazing

Comment: `$('.current').css('opacity', opacity );` try this

Comment: $(".current").css({opacity: opacity }); You don't need !important, as jqery adds style as inline, so it is higher specificitiy than class

Comment: you should give a text inside of the div, your code is working fine but don't need "cssText", line.

Comment: @shu. Your answer works well, and is the simpliest. 
Weird thing is. It works on the minimal pen, but not on my big project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your css to this

```
.box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display:none;
}
```

and your js like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".current").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

this will give you nice fadeout animation.I edited your codepen link.try this.if this is not what you want tell me.

Answer (score 2):

use this ::

```
$(".current").css("opacity" ,""+ opacity );
```

instead of

```
$(".current").css("cssText", "opacity: " + opacity + " !important;");
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var opacity = 0.7;
//Yes, the code has to use a variable. 
//NOT a static value;
$(".current").css("opacity"+","+ opacity + " !important;");
```

Comment: I don't think the semicolon `;` is needed

Answer (score 0):

cssText sets or gets the content of the rules, so you need append it to the existing rule, as it overwrites it.

```
var opacity = 0.7;
$(".current").css("cssText", $('.current').css('cssText') + "opacity: "+ opacity +" !important;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works.

```
$(function(){

   var opacity = 0.7;
   $(".current").css({"opacity": opacity });
});
```